# Looking for good summer schools on quantum field theory (especially renormalization theory) this summer

Tags: conferences, renormalization, quantum-field-theory, mp.mathematical-physics

I'm a graduate student and I'm looking for summer schools to attend this summer. Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!